# How to build a project that builds into a plugin dependency?

Tags: java, maven, classpath

Does someone has a view of what is the right pom “model”, to work on a “jar” artifact that is supposed to be used as a dependency on the execution plugin ?

The real case: I want to develop a particular class in jar, say XBean.jar, which I want to set as a dependency of the jetty-maven-plugin, since the whole jetty server is supposed to have the jar in its classpath before being started, so that the classes in the jar can be configured at server level in jetty.xml.

If I simply add the dependency on the plugin , maven will complain of a loop.

So far the only way I had it working was creating a dependency on a randomly named artifact, on which I defined the scope as system, and I provided the  link to the output package of the jar module. This is not optimal as the dependency in in fact lost.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the following structure:

```
+-- root (pom.xml)
     +--- mod-xbean (pom.xml)
     +--- mod-jetty (pom.xml)
```

Just create your classes in mod-xbean etc. in mod-jetty make the definition of the jetty-maven-plugin and add mod-xbean as a dependency to that module as well as a classpath entry for the plugin itself.

Comment: Yep! Worked perfectly! (Sorry I can't upvote yet...)